# Where I can download sample database which can be used as data warehouse?

Tags: database, data-warehouse

Where I can download sample database which can be used for data warehouse creation? It should't be sample from Microsoft (Northwind etc.).

EDIT: Sorry for not clarifying my question. At my university we have class where we must create some data warehouse and since Northwind is so popular over net then professor told us not to use this database. We will use for this SQL Server 2008 but using Northwind is forbidden.

Comment: I think it would help porvide meaningful answer if you were to clarify your question a bit and maybe tell us what you are trying to do.

Comment: If you don't want Microsoft, do you have a preferred database(s)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whatever happened to NOT Northwind?

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CommunityCallToActionNOTNorthwind.aspx

There's also SQL Data Generator from Redgate:

http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Data_Generator/index.htm

Answer (score 6):

This is a free online database data generator:
[www.generatedata.com](http://www.generatedata.com/)

You can design a table structure and let the script generate rows to populate it.
It's not exactly what you need, but I think it can help.

Answer (score 4):

I have been working with the Open Flights dataset this semester for BI. This Flight Data could work for future projects, along with anything [Kimball](http://www.kimballgroup.com/category/kimball-classics/) or Red Gate related. I enjoyed learning the difference between methodologies on this page, [Data Warehouse Architecture](http://www.jamesserra.com/archive/2012/03/data-warehouse-architecture-kimball-and-inmon-methodologies/).

[OpenFlights.org](http://openflights.org/data.html)

Additionally, it was can be downloaded on this [Visualizing Data webpage, under datasets, Global Flight Network Data.](http://www.visualizing.org/datasets/global-flights-network)

Learn more about [OpenFlights Data at DataHub](http://datahub.io/dataset/open-flights).

Also, the data was in dat files and I imported it with delimited columns in Excel. After that it wasn't that difficult to use the data. [Here was a good tutorial on importing these data files using a comma delimiter in Excel](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/import-export-text-files.html).

Also, I found this [dataset page as well that had a few other useful data examples of Enterprise Data Models on Databaseanswers.org](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/enterprise_data_models.htm).

Let me know if you find any other useful datasets learning examples.

Comment: Here's another website that had a good list of data sets to test out as well.  [Excel PowerPivot Datasets to Test out.](http://powerpivot-info.com/post/50-list-suggested-datasets-to-test-powerpivot)

Comment: I know this is 8+ yr old but apparently the Global Flight Network Data 404s. In case you know the new location.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Just use Adventure works SR4

Answer (score 0):

the best way to learn is to use AdventureWorks database. There is a relational version of it which is to demo the source data and there is star schema version of it, built from a relational one for data warehousing / OLTP system.

Download it from here - many Microsoft books on SQL Server / SSAS use this as example. A friend of mine used it to learn about data warehousing and get his first BI job.

http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/